# Raspberry Pi, how can i turn bluetooth on and off over Python script?

Tags: pi-3, python, audio, bluetooth

i want to play either a sound, which is saved on my raspberry pi as a MP3 file or send a song from my phone over bluetooth to my Pi. So i found out, that if i run a song over bluetooth and play one from a saved MP3 file, the audio output gets disturbed and isn't able to handle both sources. My idea is, to only turn bluetooth on, if i am sure, that no sound is played from a saved MP3 file. My question: how can i turn on and off bluetooth over my Python script? I want to integrate these commands in my main programm. thanks

Comment: Is this what you're looking for: 
 [Turning Bluetooth on and off using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66417181/turning-bluetooth-on-off-using-python-script)

Comment: @Sanders the answer you have linked to is for Windows machines. For RPi the commands are different.

Comment: @ukBaz Thank you for catching that.

Answer (score 3):

The Bluetooth stack on Linux is BlueZ and they make a series of APIs available using D-Bus to interface with the Bluetooth hardware.

The documentation for the various API's is available at:
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc

If you have not used D-Bus before it can be a little bit of a learning curve. There are libraries like [pydbus](https://pypi.org/project/pydbus/) that try to make it more Pythonic.

The command line tool `busctl` can be useful to experiment with how D-Bus works with BlueZ. For example `busctl tree org.bluez` will show a tree of the BlueZ objects. `/org/bluez/hci0` is normally the built in Bluetooth adapter on a Raspberry Pi.

The API for the [Bluetooth Adapter](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/adapter-api.txt#n259)  has a `Powered` property that you can use to turn the power on and off.

An example of what a script might look like to toggle the power would be:

```py
import pydbus

# DBus object paths
BLUEZ_SERVICE = 'org.bluez'
ADAPTER_PATH = '/org/bluez/hci0'

# setup dbus
bus = pydbus.SystemBus()
adapter = bus.get(BLUEZ_SERVICE, ADAPTER_PATH)

# toggle power of adapter
if adapter.Powered:
    adapter.Powered = False
else:
    adapter.Powered = True
```

In a separate terminal have `bluetoothctl` running and it will report if the script has successfully changed the power.